# Como se recorre con for python un diccionario defaultdict

Tags: python-3.x, django

Agrupé la data  usando `collections.defaultdict`. Después de agrupar 
lo que deseo es recorre esa agrupación. Con el primer `for` lo que obtengo es 
los datos 1 y 2 no puedo ingresar a su información que contiene cada uno.

Este es el código:

```
groupdict = collections.defaultdict(list)
for value in data:
    group = value[0]
    groupdict[group].append(value)
```

resultado de agrupación

```
menu = defaultdict(<class 'list'>, 
    {1: [(1, 1, '1', 1, 'Administración', 'Empresa', '1', 1, 1, '', ''),
        (1, 1, '1', 2, 'Administración', 'Perfil', '1', 1, 1, '1', '1')], 
     2: [(2, 1, '1', 10, 'Maestro', 'Documentos', '?', 1, 1, '', '')]})
```

Lo que quiero es recorrer con un `for` defaultdict.

```
for value in menu:
```

lo que contiene cada uno 1: []y 2:[]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`defaultdict()` se comporta como cualquier otro diccionario python, excepto en el aspecto que tiene cuando lo imprimes (y por supuesto en que no produce errores si intentas acceder a una clave que no existe, sino que la crea en ese caso, lo cual es la razón por la que se usan).

Aparte de eso, proporciona la misma interfaz, es decir, que se itera sobre él de la misma forma.

Y esto quiere decir que:

```
for k in diccionario:
```

lo que hará será iterar por las claves de ese diccionario, no por los valores. Una vez tienes cada clave `diccionario[k]` te dará el correspondiente valor.

También puedes hacer:

```
for k, value in diccionario.items():
  print("clave: ", k)
  print("valor:", value)
```

para iterar simultáneamente por claves y valores sin necesidad de hacer `diccionario[k]`.